# Javascript animation of CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to animate the replacement of a class in javascript?

Let's consider I have this:

```
.class1 {background-color:blue;}  
.class2 {background-color:red;}
```

Is there any Javascript library that can ease the change between the two classes? That wouldn't make the user's computer explode?

If not, what would be a good way of achieving that? A server-generated Javascript file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can do this when you have [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) loaded as well.

See the demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Here's an example specific to your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/hhEpT/

```
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.class1 {background-color:blue;}
.class2 {background-color:red;}​

<div class='class1'></div>

$('div').addClass('class2', 1000);
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but this is one of those jQuery UI features that I keep in my personal "completely crazy; avoid" file.  It's a feature that works when it works, but when it doesn't stuff just gets weird. However it does in fact exist :-)

Comment: @Pointy - Agreed. The concept is great, but in practice if I was to use it, it would only be in the simplest of cases. Probably safer to cache the styles in a variable, and use that with `.animate()` instead.

Comment: I realize this isn't always practical (especially if your CSS is more involved than just background-colors), but you could also layer `<div class="class1" />` on top of `<div class="class2" />` and simply `.fadeOut()` on hover or another event.

Comment: @peter - That could certainly be a possibility in some cases. :o)

Comment: It's not the point, really, I did want to have a system that can deal with major modifications within a CSS class. What I did realize, though, is that I'll probably never have to animate anything else than position, size, or color. Anything else would be a little flaky that I wouldn't be very much surprised...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery it is having animate function which will allow you to animate from class1 to class2.

here is a link

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for normal animations. Use jQuery UI for animation between classes as suggested in another answers.

Comment: True but you also need jQuery UI.

Comment: jQuery's `.animate()` method alone can't animate the replacement of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of **jQuery** and **jQueryUI**.

Let's say for example you have a paragraph like this:

```
<p id="notice" class="class1">This is something to highlight</p>
```

So basically you want to animate the replace of class1 with class2.  Since CSS allows you to override styles, you can simply add a new class and it will override the initial effect.

```
$("#notice").addClass("class2", 50);
```

Where 50 is obviously how long the animation takes.  For this to work you need to reference both the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) libraries.

The alternative is to use the **jQuery animate** method.  Basically you specify the css that drives the animation, the duration, and a callback.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#notice').animate(
      {background-color: yellow}, 
      5000, 
      function() {
        $("#notice").removeClass("class1");
      });
});
```